# How to write to an HTML element from the server in Dart

Tags: forms, server, dart, request, response

I am trying to learn the basics of server side Dart.  When I hit the submit element on the HTML page, the screen is cleared and replaced with "hello."  I am trying to keep all elements in place, and put the "hello" in the div place.  I have not found any basic documentation on this, so I may be missing a lot here.  Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Here is the Server code:

```
import 'dart:io';

Future main() async {
  var server = await HttpServer.bind(
    InternetAddress.loopbackIPv4,
    8080,
  );

  await for (HttpRequest request in server) {
request.response
  ..write("hello")
  ..close();
  }
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<form action="http://localhost:8080" method="GET">
<input type="text" id="name" value="name">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<div id="output"></div>  // I want the "hello" to go here
```

Comment: Did you see this example: https://webdev.dartlang.org/tutorials/get-data/fetch-data ?

Comment: Consists of several tasks. Something like a) send http get from client (code above). b) recieve http get on server(code above). c) send response from server (code above). d) recieve on client. e) display recieved data in dom element. Steps a, b, c d, could be verified with things like chrome dev tools or just plain print statements. Does this match for your project?

Comment: Yes.  I agree with the steps, but cannot get to d and e.  I think it's clear that this has to be done with dart code in the client.  That helps by itself.  I just can't find any example of getting the above to work.  I think it has something to do with changing the server side settings, but again, it's not clear.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite common to build web applications that pull in data from other web applications, initiated by logic that performs HTTP calls to third party services.

lets look at how we can use the inbuilt HttpRequest classes to make HTTP calls to external services.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>A Minimalist App</title>
  </head>

  <body>
     <div id="output">Hi</div>  // I want the "hello" to go here
    <script type="application/dart" src="main.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**main.dart**

```
import 'dart:html';
void main() {
  var response = await HttpRequest.getString('http://localhost:8080')
  querySelector('#output').text = response;
}
```

For more info visit [here](http://dartdoc.takyam.com/docs/tutorials/connect-dart-html/#dom-intro)

Thanks. :) , hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you.  This is very helpful, but it does not answer the question.  Specifically, I am trying to learn the behavior of the form element, and how it can interact with the server, if this is possible.  I may have a fundamental misunderstanding of the form element.  Your example was helpful, but it does not completely work.  What happens is that the response is sent to the div element, but then the screen changes, with the response on a new page all together.